# QR code not displaying in gmail

Tags: c#, .aspxauth

I am sending qr code in mail. when i sent mail to yahoo account , its displaying

```
<table runat="server" id="Div4" border="0" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"  >
<tr>

    <td>
        <p>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plBarCode" runat="server"  />
            </p>
        <br />
            </td>
      </tr> 

        </table>
```

Comment: Have you found any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, bluntly said, yahoo is less secure than Gmail. Gmail does not allow for parsing of asp-code, only HTML. In other words, the whole `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plBarCode" runat="server"  />` line won't do anything.

I'm suspecting it's only yahoo which allows for this behavior.